# No networks found upon returning to original location

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter, usb-network-adapter

The oddest thing is happening with my network connection. I can work on it fine at home, and then I bring it to school and it connects automatically to that network too. But then when I get back home...

- There are no networks available under Networks, although the symbol in the status bar has that little asterisk which means it's found some but hasn't connected to any.
- Sometimes Networks (brought up by clicking in the status bar) doesn't even open up when you click.
- Going into Control Panel and trying to access the adapter usually ends up being stopped at some point. For example, in Network and Sharing Center I click on Change Adapter Settings, and absolutely nothing happens. Everything else on the page works but nothing is brought up for Adapter Settings. When I try it again, sometimes it stops me even earlier in the process (e.g. it doesn't even bring up Network and Sharing Center)
- Shutting down the computer does not solve the problem; I *must* force-powercycle it to get back network connections. And then it works fine until I get home from school the next day.

It really seems to be some sort of software-end problem, but I don't have any idea what to do to fix it.

It's a Lenovo Yoga 11, 64-bit Windows 8. The adapter is a Realtek RTL8723AU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to use `services.msc` to make sure the network services are running (and maybe even manually start them if they aren't already).

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your pc in safe mode. And see if it open change adapter settings window. If it does, sounds like an issue with possible registry. In which case I recommend getting a program like CCleaner, and allow it to scan for registry issues. It will ask for backup of registry. Always do so. Then fix all issues. Restart the machine and see if it made a difference

Comment: Let me know how you went :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix it :( I have pinpointed the error to some degree. When I have my XAMPP server running, *sometimes* the adapter crashes, but I have not yet observed it to crash without XAMPP running. I'm probably just going to update XAMPP, but it takes forever to download.

Comment: While the response to this was quite a while back.

Can you confirm if your issue was resolved by updating XAMPP?